# Is Per-Monitor v2 Awareness supported by Windows Server?

Tags: windows, dpi-aware

I'm writing system requirements for our application, where we recently added support of per-monitor DPI awareness V2. We've tested it with client versions of Windows. Dos someone know if this functionality is supported by Windows Server versions, and if yes, since which version?

I've looked in MSDN but couldn't find an answer...

If it is important, we initialize DPI awareness using method described here:
[WPF ClickOnce DPI awareness Per-Monitor v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537990/wpf-clickonce-dpi-awareness-per-monitor-v2)

Comment: No.  Hooking up multiple monitors to a server is very unusual.  Commonly they have none at all and are managed remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft documentation it is only available in client Windows versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context#requirements).

> Minimum supported client : Windows 10, version 1607 [desktop apps only]
>   Minimum supported **server** : **None supported**