# WPF per monitor DPI Aware dialog positioning issue

Tags: wpf, dpi-aware

I have a WPF .Net 4.7 application with per monitor DPI Aware.
I enable the DPI awareness following the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537990/wpf-clickonce-dpi-awareness-per-monitor-v2).

I want to open a dialog at the top left corner of my mainWindow, and I do the following:

```
 var window = new Window();
 window.Owner = mainWindow;
 window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
 window.Left = mainWindow.Left;
 window.Top = mainWindow.Top;
 window.Show();
```

I have 2 monitors with different DPI scale.

If I run the application from Visual Studio, it all works fine: regardless of which monitor the mainWindow is, the dialog is always positioned at the top-left corner of the mainWindow.

But if I run the application from Windows Explorer, the dialog is positioned correctly only on the monitor in which the Windows Explorer was when I launched the application.

Why this different behaviour, and how can I correctly position the dialog when I run the application from Windows Explorer?

Comment: Launch Task Manager. Add Column "DPI Awareness". Start app with Visual Studio and check DPI Awareness. Then, start app from Windows Explorer. Are you seeing two difference values for DPI Awareness?