# Click once application won't run on windows 7, 8 after allowing dpiAware

Tags: c#

So we're trying to make sure that our application scale perfectly on 4K monitors. We successfully did that, but now the app will not run on windows 7,8,8.1. It can only run on windows 10,11.

So by uncommenting the code below, the app will not run on older windows. Is there anyway around it, where we can keep the dpiAware true for windows 10,11 and false for older versions so users with older version of windows can still run the app?

Note: i'm using .NET 4.7.2
Thanks

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
<application>
<!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on
       and is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements
       and Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment. -->

<!-- Windows Vista -->
<!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->-->

<!-- Windows 7 -->
<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

<!-- Windows 8 -->
<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

<!-- Windows 8.1 -->
<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />

<!-- Windows 10 -->
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

</application>
</compatibility>


<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
  <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
  <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
</windowsSettings>
</application>
```

Comment: Hmm, this manifest shouldn't work at all for ClickOnce-deployed apps.  Consider [using pinvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43537991/17034).