# QQuickView title bar too large on secondary monitor

Tags: python, qml, dpi, pyside2

The title bar for my `QQuickView` Qt application is too big when I move the window to my secondary monitor. It displays correctly on my primary monitor. The title bar is the correct size if I use `QWidget` instead of `QQuickView`.

Is it possible to make the title bar display correctly for a `QQuickView` application? If so, how?

I am using PySide2 version 5.15.0 on Windows 10 version 1803. My primary monitor DPI is set to 125%, and my secondary monitor is set to 100%. The application is running as "per-monitor DPI aware". The [Qt documentation on high DPI support](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) didn't have anything helpful for resolving this. I played around with various DPI settings and environment variables.

**test.py**

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
    view.setSource(QUrl('view.qml'))
    view.show()

    app.exec_()
```

**view.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 200
    color: "green"

    Text {
        text: "Hello World"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

*Thanks to @eyllanesc for the hint on how to try a different renderer.*

Configure Qt to use the ANGLE renderer by adding one of the following lines before instantiating the `QApplication` object:

```
QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseOpenGLES)
```

```
os.environ['QT_OPENGL'] = 'angle'
```

See [Qt 5 on Windows ANGLE and OpenGL](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5_on_Windows_ANGLE_and_OpenGL) for implications.

## Background

There seem to be some longstanding issues with scaling the non-client area (title bar) properly in Qt Quick applications with the OpenGL renderer on Windows.

Qt bug report [QTBUG-78143](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-78143) is about non-client items not being scaled when `dpiawareness` is `2`. The bug is closed as a problem with Windows that Microsoft is aware of, but has not fixed.

There is also the older [QTBUG-65804](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65804) which talks about the same problem.

[QTBUG-68712](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68712) talks about implementing a new Windows value, [`DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context), but that it would bring back an older bug until Microsoft fixes something.

I found [an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864894/scaling-the-non-client-area-title-bar-menu-bar-for-per-monitor-high-dpi-suppo/43234355#43234355) which has a lot of discussion too.

Comment: You say: *but I am a Qt newbie and I don't know how to do that!*, then try add `os.environ["QT_OPENGL"] = "angle"` before `app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])`. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers